# Como puedo detectar un cambio a tiempo real con jquery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, html5

tengo una duda como puedo detectar un cambio a tiempo real para que me deshabilite o habilite un boton.
tengo la funcion que llama al archivo php para mostrarme cuantos productos tengo en el array y si tengo 0 me lo desactiva, pero si tengo agrego no me lo quita, a manos que actualice la pagina, probé en el else, quitandole el disable, pero no hubo cambios

```
    $(document).ready(Principales);
```

function Principales(){

```
actualizarCarritoUIY();
disable();
```

}

function disable(){

```
fetch('http://localhost/tienda/api/carrito/api-carrito.php?action=mostrar')

.then(response=> response.json())
.then(data =>{
    let = contador = data.info.count;
    console.log(contador);

    if(contador===0){            
        $('#pagar-carrito').attr("disabled", true);
        $('#pagar-carro').attr("disabled", true);

    }else{
        console.log("Tienes " +contador+ " productos");

    }

});
```

}

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el cambio que debe detectar?

Comment: Lo siento, pasé a darle a enviar, y no terminaba de generar la duda, ahí la edite, la cosa es qeu debe detectar cuando el array o el carro tenga 1 o + productos, y volver a habilitar el boton o los 2 en este caso

Comment: En el _else_, después de mostrar el mensaje con total de productos, [elimina el atributo _disabled_](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) de ambos botones.